# Proving well ordering principle with well ordering principle

Tags: integers, axioms, well-orders

Hypothesis:
"Every nonempty subset S of the positive integers has a least element."
Goal:
"Every nonempty subset S of non-negative integers has a least element."

Is this proof possible? I was able to prove it the other way around but failed to prove it this way. So I wonder if it's possible and how would I prove it.

Comment: What was the obstruction you encountered with your proof?

Comment: @EricTowers I tried to split the goal into two case where elements in S = 0, or elements in S>0. But there's some logic error and I can't use the my hypothesis to finish the proof for the second case.

Comment: Wouldn't the two cases by either (1) $0 \in S$ or (2) $0 \not\in S$?

Comment: I think I see it now. If 0∈S, then 0 is the least element. If 0∉S, then it's exactly my hypothesis.